# Why is there a Maximum bytecode to permit for a contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, quorum

Why is there a Maximum bytecode to permit for a contract in Quorum?

i.e., MaxCodeSize = 24576 // Maximum bytecode to permit for a contract.

One should be allowed to deploy a smart contract of any size in a permissioned/private blockchain such as Quorum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an Ethereum core question than Quorum. The size tho is determined by EVM processing and the logic is explained here: https://github.com/comaeio/porosity/wiki/Ethereum-Internals

Comment: Got it. Other than breaking down the contract, can one tweak the code size allowing one huge contract to be deployed?

Comment: i have updated the MaxCodeSize in protocol_params.go but it did not work. Oversized data is still return? Any workarounds? This is urgent